# Search for an specific asset inside a transaction

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to make a Composer transaction that, given the asset that I introduce as a parameter for the transaction, it searches another type of assets for one that has some common parameters.

Model:

```
namespace org.acme.sample

abstract asset Generic identified by ID {
 o String ID
 --> Owner owner
}

asset Asset1 extends Generic{
 o Boolean done
}

asset Asset2 extends Generic{
}

participant Owner identified by ownerID{
  o String ownerID
  o String ownerName
}

transaction Transaction {
  --> Asset2 in
}
```

So, given that model, what I want to do is the following (something like this, at least):

```
function Transaction (tx){
  var aux = query('org.acme.sample.Asset1', {owner.ownerID : tx.in.owner.ownerID})
  aux.done = true
  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.Asset1')
   .then(function (assetRegistry) {
       return assetRegistry.update(aux);
   })
}
```

This is more close to pseudo-code than anything else (I don't believe queries work like that, but thats my big uncertainty)
Let's imagine that the query is precise enough to just found one valid asset.

That, theoretically, would put in aux an Asset1 that has the same ownerID as the Asset2 given in parameters, and it would change its done boolean. Problem is, everything I try wont work, I don't know how to use a query like this inside a transaction (I've tried also to do a separate query, but I had no luck making it work).

I hope someone's able to help me with this :D

Comment: You need to read the documentation for queries and describe what you've tried, the errors you are getting and include links to your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a query. You can do this by adding a `queries.qry` file in the main directory of your Composer project. For example the query can be like such:

```
query getSpecificAsset1 {
  description: "Get a specific task with id"
  statement:
    SELECT org.acme.sample.Asset1
      WHERE (owner == _$ownerID)
}
```

Then you can use this query in a transaction processor function, for example:

```
function updateAsset(tx) {
// tx.in.owner is the ID from Asset2
// this query will return a Asset1 with the same ID
  return query('getSpecificAsset1', { owner: tx.in.owner })
  .then(function (asset) {        
    var serializer = getSerializer();
    var json = serializer.toJSON(asset);
    json.done = true
    return getAssetRegistry("org.acme.sample.Asset1")
    .then(function(asset1Registry) {
      return asset1Registry.updateAll([json]);
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
  // Add optional error handling here.
  throw new Error(error);
  });
}
```